# Passing functions as argument when functions have different signatures

Tags: swift, function, methods

I red lots of answers but I could not find a definitive answer to my question.

In Swift, I have 3 (or more) different methods. The only thing they have in common is their return type, eg.

```
A(a:String)->MyType
B(a:Int,b:String,c:AnyObject,d:Whatever)->MyType
C(a:Int,b:String,c:Other)->MyType
```

I need to pass the functions as an argument of a class method, eg.

```
myClass.configureIOTDevice(configFile:String, functionToCall:A)
```

Then, inside the body of this method I want to call:

```
functionToCall()
```

As you can see, a problem arises: how to pass the needed arguments for different signatures?

Any help, tip and, why not, rotten tomato is appreciated   :-)

Comment: Who is supplying the values for the arguments? Could they be passed in as well? Perhaps in a dictionary?

Comment: @vacawama Of course, I could create MyType before passing it, but my question was... sort of a theoretical question  ;-)

Comment: You can wrap your function in a closure that takes a dictionary of type `[String: Any]` and unpacks it and calls your function.  Then you'd pass the dictionary and the `([String: Any]) -> MyType` closure to your function and it would call `functionToCall(dict)` when the time comes.

Comment: I was hoping in `perform` and `NSSelectorFromString`, but they are a little limited

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this

```
func getData( functionToCall : Any) {
    if let function = functionToCall as? ()-> Void {
        function()
    }
    else if let function = functionToCall as? (String, String) -> Int {
        let result = function("a","b")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are answering my question?

Comment: YES man. What you want? Should I paste exactly your code. You have functionToCall, pass any signature to it. Now depending upon what signature is passed call it.

Comment: ok, thanks, but I was looking for something different, this solution can become difficult to maintain (everytime you add a new function you must adjust this getData function too: am I right? Or am I missing something?)

Comment: This is the best we can do. As you can see this would be callback. So, when it call fuctionToCall it would need to know the parameter to be passed to functionToCall. Right? Now if you add another function definition getData needs to be updated to pass and call the correct method. Without that it would be impossible. How can you call functionToCall like functionToCall() when it should be funtionToCall(String, Int... etc)?.

Comment: Ok, as I said before, I was hoping in some `perform`, `NSSelectorFromString` or reflection magics